# Alertdialog can't show on getview

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I can't show the Dialog,i try but return null pointer.
The problem , I Think is the context, i have tried with this but obtain the same result...
Another possibility , I think, is to open a thread and inside the Main Activity show the AlertDialog , this is my code:

**file Sector1.java** 
   public class Sector1 extends Fragment
    {

```
    private Button btnNew_order,btnAggiungi;
    private Spinner spin_prodotto, spin_tipo;
    private EditText EtQta;
    ListView userList;
    static UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sector1, container, false);

            userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.row, userArray);
            userList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

**UserCustomAdapter.java**

```
   public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
     private static final int INVISIBLE = 4;
     private static final int VISIBLE = 0;
    Context context;
     int layoutResourceId;
     ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,  ArrayList<User> data) {
                  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
                  this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                  this.context = context;
                  this.data = data;
             }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          View row = convertView;
          UserHolder holder = null;

          System.out.println("@@@-getView-@@@");
          if (row == null) {

               //LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
               LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
               row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
               holder = new UserHolder();
               holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_prodotto);
               holder.textQta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_qta);
               //holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
               holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
               holder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);

           row.setTag(holder);
          } else {
           holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
          }

          User user = data.get(position);
          holder.Useritem = data.get(position);
          holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
          holder.textQta.setText(user.getQta());
          //holder.textLocation.setText(user.getLocation());

          holder.btnDelete.setTag(holder.Useritem);// mi segno la posizione in modo da recuperarla poi in seguito!!
          holder.btnEdit.setTag(holder.Useritem);// mi segno la posizione in modo da recuperarla poi in seguito!!

          //rendo invisibili i pulsanti per la prima riga
          if(position == 0){
              holder.btnDelete.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
              holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
          }else{
              holder.btnDelete.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
              holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          }
          holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
            showDialog();
           }
          });

          holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete item",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                User itemToRemove = (User)v.getTag();
                Sector1.userAdapter.remove(itemToRemove);
                Sector1.userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
          });
          return row;
     }

   private void showDialog(){
           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
           AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();      
           alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
           alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do ???");
           alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
           alertDialog.show();
        }

        static class UserHolder {
          TextView textName;
          TextView textQta;
          //TextView textLocation;
          ImageButton btnEdit;
          ImageButton btnDelete;
          User Useritem;
         } 
    }
```

**NoticeDialogFragment.java**

public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

```
/* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
 * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
 * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
NoticeDialogListener mListener;

// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Build the dialog and set up the button click handlers
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("ciaoo")
           .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
               }
           });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

**on MainActivity.java**

```
    public void showNoticeDialog() {
            // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
            DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
        }
// The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
    // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
    // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
        Toast.makeText(this, "Positive button Clicked",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button
        Toast.makeText(this, "Negative button Clicked",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
```

I would like to implement the second version of Dialog by call **showNoticeDialog()**, if I call this function on MainActivity all is OK, but how can call this function on my getView above?

this is my LOG for the first dialog metod:

```
10-10 19:41:49.206: D/MainActivity(9150): MainActivity.onCreate
10-10 19:41:49.218: D/MainActivity(9150): MainActivity.onStart
10-10 19:41:49.218: D/MainActivity(9150): MainActivity.onResume
10-10 19:41:49.278: W/EGL_emulation(9150): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
....
10-10 19:41:52.914: I/Edit Button Clicked(9150): **********
10-10 19:41:52.914: D/AndroidRuntime(9150): Shutting down VM
10-10 19:41:52.918: W/dalvikvm(9150): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa622c288)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:589)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.bandweb.ordinifornitori.UserCustomAdapter.showDialog(UserCustomAdapter.java:148)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.bandweb.ordinifornitori.UserCustomAdapter.access$0(UserCustomAdapter.java:142)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.bandweb.ordinifornitori.UserCustomAdapter$1.onClick(UserCustomAdapter.java:121)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-10 19:41:52.918: E/AndroidRuntime(9150):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what context are you passing in the constructor ? applicationContext ?

Comment: First of all you have to be more clear about what you try to do. What is the task that you want to achieve, in what context? In your description you mention something about a Dialog, but in the code you show us an ArrayAdapter. What Dialog you want to show and why? And how do you plan to use that adapter? Also show a complete trace of the error log - there can be a "caused by" somewhere down bellow that is useful.

Comment: did you find out the problem ??

Answer (score 5):

You did not show the alertdialog yet. Try it

```
   AlertDialog dialog;
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);     
   alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
   alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do ???");
   alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
   dialog = alertDialog .create();
   dialog .show();
```

You just have to show the alertdialog, not the builder. And here you use the perfect context which is initialized through your constructor. happy programming ..

Comment: comment the sentence sysyem.out.println()  ,then compile it

Comment: and also change the layoutinflater initialization like LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to send activity for using it context?

On the other hand you should extract a method something like below.

```
private void showDialog(){
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();      
   alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
   alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do ???");
   alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
   alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the

```
alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
   alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do ???");
   alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
   alertDialog.show();
```

with

```
dialog.setTitle("Conformation");
       dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do ???");
       dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
       dialog.show();
```